# Problema ao ler uma String em C

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber porque o meu programa não aceita de jeito nenhum a leitura do nome do segundo e do terceiro aluno. Já usei o comando de limpeza de buffer, que é o fflush(stdin) e ele ainda não fez o mesmo. Continua ignorando o nome e lendo apenas o código e as 3 notas do aluno.

```
struct alunos a[3];
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    printf("Digite o nome do funcionario : ");
    gets(a[i].nome);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Digite o codigo do aluno : ");
    scanf("%d",&a[i].codigo);

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        printf("Digite a %d nota : ",j+1);
        scanf("%f",&a[i].notas[j]);
    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Já que você está utilizando `fflush(stdin);`, cujo comportamento é indefinido e não funciona em todos os ambientes, tente colocar antes do `gets(a[i].nome);`.

Comment: Obrigado, tinha testado usando o comando scanf com o fflush depois e funcionou. Realizei agora com a sua sugestão e também deu certo!!